# check if 'group' entity type is associated with the user, then... - drupal 7 templates user-profile.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

how can I check for a group entity type associated with the user (im using the group module http://drupal.org/project/group) from inside the user-profile.tpl.php template?

I have a use case for new users where I need to check for a group associated with the user, if it does not exist, then I want to show a button with a link to the 'create group' page.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with the group module.  With Organic Groups module, that context is available through the `og_context()` function and is available on any page.  I've never used the group module, but since the group is a fieldable entity, it would make sense that you would want to edit the user entity and add an entity reference to it, or use the relationship between the group entity and the user to find this information.  If you're not into coding you might want to look at Organic Groups module instead, as it is much more widely used and supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, im a designer, which is why i need code examples to work with. ive been using the group module as a test and im really liking the functionality as compared to Organic Groups. Only a few small items are keeping me from launching.

I was thinking I could access it from $global_user as Ive done something similar before checking for a particular "role" and doing something. Im just trying to add a simple helper function for new users to be able to create a new group easily.